# moongose db or kwyword in where clasue

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, mongoose

how to put or condition in mongoose where clause like we do in sql 
select * from tablename where col='test' or col2 ='test1'

> this.find(criteria)
>         .sort({'createdAt': -1}) // sort by date
>         .limit(options.perPage)
>         .skip(options.perPage * options.pagenum)
>         .where($or: [{'category' : options.category},{'title' :{$regex : options.search}}])
>         .exec(cb);

Comment: What did you try to do after your question? Please format it correctly and try to explain your question well

Answer (score 0):

You can do that;

```
Model.find({col: "test", col2="test1"}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
    // error
    } else {
    // result
    }
});
```